# Handle undefined fields Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I use py-elasticsearch with bulk feature e.g.:

```
//loop
   action = {
    "_index": "venue",
    "_type": "venue",
    "_id": tempid,
    "_source": item
   }
   actions.append(action)

helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

However in my results  I see:

```
"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "venue",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "52e6d42fc36b4408dbe907d1",
        "_score": 4.0977435,
        "_source": {
           "city": "Athens",
           "name": "Half Note Jazz Club",
           "address": "17 Trivonianou Street",
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "venue",
        "_type": "venue",
        "_id": "530391abc36b442b25e8a514",
        "_score": 4.023251,
        "_source": {
           "city": null,   <--- this
           "name": "life Jazz Cafe-bar",               
           "address": null  <---- and this
        }
     }
  ]
```

Assuming that when I "bulk-feed" ES I have not defined the city and the address, is there a way to have those fields omitted in ES as well?

Or will ES always create a null value even if this document does not have this field?
Is ES by architecture this way or should I search for a bug in my code?

**Update**

My full mapping is the following:

```
<type>: {
    mappings: {
        <index>: {
            properties: {                
                address: {
                    type: "string"
                },
                city: {
                    type: "string"
                },
                country: {
                    type: "string"
                },
                location: {
                    properties: {
                        coordinates: {
                            type: "geo_point"
                        },
                        type: {
                            type: "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                name: {
                    type: "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with py-elasticsearch, but either the bug is in the library or in your code as the `_source` field always returns exactly what was sent to elasticsearch in the first place.

Comment: Thanks I started this [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/issues/57) but review my code again and it should be my own fault.

Answer (score 0):

The null_value in your mapping would be "null". So if you want to omit a field which is not present in the document to be indexed, dont specify the null_value in the mapping[null_value](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html)

Comment: I agree with you. However I have not specified a null_value.